# renamed in 1946 as 7-Eleven

Tags: prepositions, collocations, error

The preposition "as" is not normally used with the verb "renamed," is it? Why is it used in the following?

> To reflect their extended hours of operation, the stores were renamed in 1946 **as** 7-Eleven: open from 7 a.m. to 11 p.m.

https://edition.cnn.com/2023/03/14/business/japan-billionaire-7-eleven-masatoshi-ito-death-intl-hnk/index.html

Comment: I don't know if this is a complete answer, but just "...renamed in 1946 7-11" sounds strange and a little confusing because of the big string of numbers ("nineteen forty six seven eleven").

Comment: Would you leave the "as" as is?

Comment: Answered on ELU: [Which preposition to use with "rename"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/100296/191178)

Comment: @Laurel: Not very well answered, I feel. The top answer on that ELU link claims that *“Rename A **to** B” is common and correct. “Rename A **as** B” is **uncommon** and correct.* Which is completely untrue, as the chart in my answer below shows.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the preposition "as" can be used with the verb "rename". Including "as" is optional. (This is also true with some other verbs, such as "consider".) For example, here is a recent headline:

> [HBO Max Renamed as Max](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/business/digital/hbo-max-renamed-max-streaming-warner-bros-discovery-1235371531/)

(J. Clara Chan, *The Hollywood Reporter*, 12 April 2023)

Comment: Thank you. Somehow the pattern "rename A as B" is not listed in the dictionary.

Comment: As this NGram graph shows, "rename _NOUN_ as" only became common in the1980s: I suspect that this is expression came into being when describing renaming computer files. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rename+_NOUN_+as&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @JavaLatte: Not sure that chart tells us much of relevance here. I just changed **rename _NOUN_ as** to **rename _NOUN_ to** and got almost exactly the same chart. BUT if you do both searches on a single chart, and switch between BrE and AmE, you'll see the same usage split I flagged up in my answer. Bear in mind there's no chance that British and American computer languages or Operating System command syntax would have reflected that difference - we were all using the same computer languages and OSes, obviously!

Answer (score 2):

The choice of preposition has no significance, but it's worth noting that there ***is*** a "significant" (noticeable but *meaningless*) difference depending on which side of the Atlantic you are...

[American English...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has%20been%20renamed%20as%2Chas%20been%20renamed%20to&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=10)

[image]

[British English...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has%20been%20renamed%20as%2Chas%20been%20renamed%20to&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=10)

[image]